# How to create a dynamic variable name by concatenating two strings

Tags: variables, go

I want to a create variable name by concatenating with current date and provide a value to the created variable name. My variable name should look something like this **"Key-2019-01"** so that I can store the value as **var Key-2019-01 = "yes"**

I have tried like the below.

```
     package main

     import (
         "fmt"
         "time"
         "strconv"
          "strings" 
     )

    func main() {
        currentMonth := time.Now().Month()
        currentYear := time.Now().Year()
        var month = int(currentMonth)
        var currentDate = strings.Join([]string{strconv.Itoa(currentYear), "-", strconv.Itoa(month)}, "")

        var "Key",currentDate string

        value, err := json.Marshal("yes")
        stub.PutState(("Key", currentDate), value)
    }
```

It could be helpful if I get a working code of this.

Comment: no this is golang.if there is way for this in solution in javascript. i thought of trying the logic in golang

Comment: Dynamic variable name is not what you want.  Have a look at a key/value pair... https://gobyexample.com/maps  (Also I removed the irrelevant tags)

Comment: is there a possibility that i can create a variable name by concatenating with current date and assign a value to the variable?

Comment: This is not possible in Go.

Comment: ok thank you @Flimzy

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Go, since it's a compiled and statically typed language. The compiler has to know, at compile-time, the names and types of variables (*). What you ask is a run-time variable naming, which cannot work. However, it's extremely unlikely that you actually need this in practice. Maps can provide a similar capability:

```
m := make(map[string]string)
m["key"] = "value"
```

And you can construct either of these at run-time. Slightly adapting your example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    currentMonth := time.Now().Month()
    currentYear := time.Now().Year()
    var month = int(currentMonth)
    var currentDate = strings.Join([]string{strconv.Itoa(currentYear), "-", strconv.Itoa(month)}, "")

    m["key"+currentDate] = "value"
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Prints out:

```
map[key2019-1:value]
```

---

(*) With some exceptions that are not relevant for this particular discussion.